# How to Upgrade from Entity Framework 4.0 to 4.3

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I have a project that uses Entity Framework 4.0.  From within that project, I installed 4.3.  Some changes appeared in my app.config indicating that I was now using 4.3.  However, my generated code still inherits from ObjectContext and creates ObjectSets even if I delete and re-add the edmx.  How do I get the generator to use DbContext and DbSets?

Answer (score 1):

You must download [DbContext T4 template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2) from Visual studio gallery - you can get it from extension manager in Visual studio.

Comment: And turn off the code generation that came with the edmx...and set the edmx filename in the two scripts.  This is the answer, and I appreciate it, but I prefer the scripts that create all the entities in one file.  I put hand-coded classes in their own files, but I prefer the generated ones all in one place.